# Powershell: Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal Error

Tags: file, powershell, crash

The code:

```
$ServerListFile = "D:\Scripts\ServerList.txt"   
$ServerList = Get-Content $ServerListFile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue  
$Result = @() 

ForEach($computername in $ServerList)  
{ 

$AVGProc = Get-WmiObject -computername $computername win32_processor |  
Measure-Object -property LoadPercentage -Average | Select Average 
$OS = gwmi -Class win32_operatingsystem -computername $computername | 
Select-Object @{Name = "MemoryUsage"; Expression = {“{0:N2}” -f ((($_.TotalVisibleMemorySize - $_.FreePhysicalMemory)*100)/ $_.TotalVisibleMemorySize) } 

Get-Eventlog -LogName Security -Newest 5000 | Where-Object {$_.EventID -eq "4624"} | Select-Object @{Name ='Username'; Expression = {$_.ReplacementStrings[1]}}
} 

$result += [PSCustomObject] @{  
        ServerName = "$computername" 
        CPULoad = "$($AVGProc.Average)%" 
        MemLoad = "$($OS.MemoryUsage)%" 
        EventLog = "$username"
    } 

    $Outputreport = "<HTML><TITLE> Server Health Report </TITLE> 
                     <BODY background-color:peachpuff> 
                     <font color =""#99000"" face=""Microsoft Tai le""> 
                     <H2> Server Health Report </H2></font> 
                     <Table border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0> 
                     <TR bgcolor=gray align=center> 
                       <TD><B>Server Name</B></TD> 
                       <TD><B>Avrg.CPU Utilization</B></TD> 
                       <TD><B>Memory Utilization</B></TD>
                       <TD><B>Username Event-4624</B></TD></TR>" 

    Foreach($Entry in $Result)  

        {  
          if((($Entry.CpuLoad) -or ($Entry.memload)) -ge 80 )  
          {  
            $Outputreport += "<TR bgcolor=red>"  
          }  
          else 
           { 
            $Outputreport += "<TR>"  
          } 
          $Outputreport += "<TD>$($Entry.Servername)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.CPULoad)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.MemLoad)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.EventLog)</TD></TR>"  
        } 
     $Outputreport += "</Table></BODY></HTML>"  
        }  

$Outputreport | out-file D:\Scripts\Test.htm  
Invoke-Expression D:\Scripts\Test.htm
```

Produces the following error:

```
Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal.

At D:\Scripts\AGAIN.PS1:13 char:13

+ Get-Eventlog <<<<  -LogName Security -Newest 5000 | Where-Object {$_.EventID -eq "4624"} | Select-Object @{Name ='Username'; Expression = {$_.ReplacementStrings[1]}}

+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEqualsInHashLiteral
```

Comment: Why don't you briefly explain your script?

Comment: Hi Paolo,  I am working on a Decommission Project of above 15000 servers, and the process is manual and killing, So I am looking for powershell scripts to do the whole process.  from the lists of server in ServerList.txt. The scripts should check the CPU and memory usage, check in Security log for event ID 4624 and also check the date of the last access shared folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

missing a `}` here:

```
Select-Object @{Name = "MemoryUsage"; Expression = {"{0:N2}" -f ((($_.TotalVisibleMemorySize - $_.FreePhysicalMemory)*100)/ $_.TotalVisibleMemorySize) } }
```